# AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: newRoom

Tags: python, flask

I am creating a game. I want it so that a player calls the "room/new_game", a new URL is created for them and a new newroom.html is rendered. Everything is fine the first time but if a another user tries to host their own room, I get an error.

Here is an example process I want:

1. A client goes to index.html and hits "Host Game" which is tied to "@app.route('/room/new_game', methods=['POST'])".
2. Server creates a new game object and it has the room code: aaaa.
3. The server creates a new url for that room. Something like "/room/aaaa".
4. The server sends the room code to the client.
5. Client goes to /room/aaaa.

Here's my code

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", server=server)

@app.route('/room/new_game', methods=['POST'])
def newGame():
    game = Games.Game
    result = {}
    result["game_code"] = game.room_code

    @app.route('/room/' + game.room_code)
    def newRoom():
        return render_template("newroom.html", room_code=game.room_code.upper())
    return jsonify(result)
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ianc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ianc/Documents/OneNightUltimateWerewolf/test.py", line 35, in newGame
    @app.route('/room/' + game.room_code)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1250, in decorator
    self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 66, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1221, in add_url_rule
    'existing endpoint function: %s' % endpoint)
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: newRoom
192.168.14.15 - - [03/Mar/2021 00:51:30] "POST /room/new_game HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```py
@app.route('/room/' + game.room_code)
    def newRoom():
        return render_template("newroom.html", room_code=game.room_code.upper())
    return jsonify(result)
```

with

```
redirect(url_for('newRoom'))
```

Take a look at this documentation https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#redirects-and-errors for more detail.

Comment: Hi Keiron, Where exactly would I use redirect(url_for('newRoom'))? Also, I've updated the post for the exact process I want. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Hi Ian, I updated my answer. Does that clear it up?

Comment: Not Really. How would that work? Doesn't url_for() point to a method? If I replace the text, the newRoom method wouldn't exist and url_for("newRoom") would be pointing to something that doesn't exist. I could be wrong. I'm pretty new to Flask